# How to encrypt my password in php

Tags: passwords

In my php application,I have encode to a password and it pass as random encrypt form with every request but if i copy previous encrypt password and paste in another user request, it logged in. I have tested in burp suite application.

How to solve the above problem,Please any one help me out.

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use password\_hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is not recommended to send the password for every request. This is a typical case for a session, or for an authentication service. Both generate a random token, which can be sent instead of the original password.